# Felix Klein's view on algebraic geometry

Tags: group-theory, geometry, algebraic-geometry

I think, as a first approach one would say that a geometry on a set $X$ is given by an inner product on $X$. Klein then links geometry to group theory by identifying a geometry on $X$ with a group of automorphisms on $X$.

So now comes algebraic geometry. Here the geometric data is in the form of sheafs of functions on the space $X$. But is there a canonical way to get a group of transformations or an inner product out of this data, i.e. is there any connection to "Klein's geometry"?

Comment: Of course varieties don't have to carry an "inner product". Perhaps intersection products and cup products are what you are looking for? I wouldn't agree that the geometric data of a variety comes in form of the structure sheaf - this is the *algebraic* data. The geometric data is the topology.

Comment: _"The geometric data is the topology."_ I think this is too simple. For me, Algebraic Geometry is a study of geometric objects by means of algebraic tools. But as the underlying topology doesn't characterize the structure sheaf, I wouldn't say that the geometric data is encoded in the topology. Also I would say that topological, smooth, analytic, etc. manifolds should be considered different geometric objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interpret Klein's point of view on geometry very, very broadly as being the following: *geometry is dictated by the morphisms you choose between geometric objects*. In the usual interpretation "morphism" is taken to mean "isomorphism," but from the point of view of category theory there's no reason to make this restriction. In other words, geometry is dictated by the choice of a category of geometric objects.

The geometry in algebraic geometry is dictated by the fact that the morphisms we choose to care about are algebraic; that is, that they are ultimately built out of polynomials. This is what distinguishes it from, say, differential geometry, where the morphisms we choose to care about are built out of smooth functions instead.

Comment: It seems like an argument could be made that really the Kleinan point of view is that geometry should be dictated by locally ringed spaces, and maps of locally ringed spaces. The further specification to schemes, or manifolds, is dictated more by what you want the defining charts of your locally ringed space to be.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: So are you saying that geometry is category theory? Just call the objects of categories geometric objects?

Comment: @Adrian: that's probably too reductive (and most geometers would probably disagree) but I think it's a reasonable starting point for an interpretation of Klein's point of view in algebraic geometry. Certainly it is too restrictive to talk about symmetry groups.

Comment: I agree; categories seem good starting points in general :) One certainly would the category in question to require existence of pushouts and pullbacks. (So you can glue und intersect)

Comment: I think I really start to appreciate your answer: For example you have the forgetful functor from smooth manifolds to topological spaces, i.e. by focusing on some objects and restricting the morphisms, you get a different "geometric category". Then, once you have such a category $C$ and an object $x$ in it, you get a group $Aut_C(x)$. Maybe Klein would call this group the "geometry" of $x$? What do you think?